# How to reference dependency installed globally on computer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm building a package (let's call it project a) that i'm trying to include in another project (project b).

In project b, I have this in my package.json

```
...
"dependencies": {
    "a": "C:\\Users\\myuser\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\a"
  },
...
```

but when I run `npm install` in project b, I get the error:

```
npm ERR! notarget No compatible version found: 1@'C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\a'
npm ERR! notarget Valid install targets:
npm ERR! notarget ["1.0.0","1.0.1","1.0.2","1.0.3","1.0.4","1.0.5","1.0.6"]
```

Versions 1.0.0 - 1.0.6 are published (although don't work).

Why doesn't npm install look at the path that I specified instead of looking in the NPM public repo?

Answer (score 1):

Because that’s not a type of source that npm recognizes. See package.json(5):

```
dependencies
       Dependencies are specified with a simple hash of package name  to  ver‐
       sion  range.  The  version  range  is  a  string  which has one or more
       space-separated descriptors.  Dependencies can also be identified  with
       a tarball or git URL.

       Please  do  not  put test harnesses or transpilers in your dependencies
       hash.  See devDependencies, below.

       npm help  See semver for more details about specifying version ranges.

       ·   version Must match version exactly

       ·   >version Must be greater than version

       ·   >=version etc

       ·   <version

       ·   <=version

       ·   npm help   ~version  "Approximately  equivalent  to  version"   See
           semver

       ·   npm help  ^version "Compatible with version"  See semver

       ·   1.2.x 1.2.0, 1.2.1, etc., but not 1.3.0

       ·   http://... See 'URLs as Dependencies' below

       ·   * Matches any version

       ·   "" (just an empty string) Same as *

       ·   version1 - version2 Same as >=version1 <=version2.

       ·   range1 || range2 Passes if either range1 or range2 are satisfied.

       ·   git... See 'Git URLs as Dependencies' below

       ·   user/repo See 'GitHub URLs' below
```

Run `npm link` inside `C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\a` instead and set a regular dependency in your `package.json`.

Comment: Running `C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\a\npm link` gives me the error `May not delete: C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\a`. Why is it trying to delete the folder?

Comment: That might just be where `npm link` puts things on Windows, actually. Does your package work without listing the dependency?

Comment: I believe that is where windows puts it by default. If you're referring to package B working without having package A as a dependency, yes but it obviously doesn't allow me to use stuff from package A.

Comment: This just seems like it should be so simple. I'm just trying to reference a dependency that is on my local system and not published to the npm repo.

Comment: @Catfish: Well, no, it’s not obvious. Did you try it?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want me to try?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install my locally built dependency by running `npm install C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\a` in the project that I wanted to consume the dependency.